# Can I distill contaminated wine?

Tags: wine, contamination, distillation

15 days ago I started a batch of wine from a Wine Kit. I went to measure the SG to begin the next step when I found the wine had a film layer at the top. Anyway I phoned the place that sold it to me and am getting a new wine kit tomorrow.

Before I pour this contaminated wine down the toilet, I am wondering if I could finish the process and distill it? Can I do anything to salvage this ~21L of bad juice?

Here's a picture of the contamination, it looked more like a white film before I poked it with a thermometer then it cracked:
[image]

Comment: Did it ferment? If not then no point in distilling it. By the way, polishing a turd just makes for a shiny turd.

Comment: @Escoce Yep it fermented. I am not hoping to make this wine better or shine it up, just making use instead of dumping. The wine actually seems OK now that it's in the second stage. A person on another forum suggested the issue was pellicle. So nothing vitally wrong with the wine.

Comment: Update: the distilled wine (Brandy) turned out great. My only complaint is it only lasted a few days :-)

Comment: Nice, how long did you let it age? And also how much brandy did you get from it?

Comment: @Escoce Tbh I didn't let it age at all, was too excited to try it. I got about 4L from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can! You are just distilling the alcohol, not all the bad stuff. If you catch it before it turns to vinegar you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what type of contamination it is, it's hard to tell if anything can be done.
Is it a white film? Does it smell bad?  A small film isn't always contamination, it could be soap residue, etc.

I am inclined to think that if contamination results in bad taste, that some of the bad taste will be tranferred during the distillation process (Garbage In -> Garbage Out).

This is particularly true with vinager, maybe less with distillation.

Comment: It is a white film, I'll attach a photo. Their is no smell, it still smells like wine. I don't mind a bad taste, just worried about getting sick

Comment: Added an image and description